# Using the StateMachineCompiler(SMC) in own code

Tags: c#, state, state-machine

Hello i want to use the State Machine Compiler (SMC) with C#
http://smc.sourceforge.net/

i have created the sm-File to describe the state machine and generated c# code from it.

Then i created my own class MyClass,add the generated class which was generated with smc and implement the methods.

My Problem is how can i run this statemachine? With a While-loop, a async call or the Task Library ? What is an elegant way?

The Statemachine is a behaivior for sending data throught the serialport. So that the user can call MyClass.Send(Data) and the StateMachine should work behind the curtains.

Can someone give me an example how to use the statemachine in own code?

Regards
rubiktubik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used SMC in many application and I was very satisfied with it. I hit the same problem as you. SMC generates code for C# which is synchronous and linear. This means if you issue a transaction by calling fsm.YourTransaction() and by chance somewhere in the middle of that transaction you issue another transaction, it would be directly called. It is very dangerous, because it breaks the base principle of a state machine - that transactions are atomic and the system is guaranteed to be in single state, or single transition all the time.
When I realized this hidden problem I implemented an asynchronous layer above the state machine code generated by SMC. Unfortunately I cannot provide you with the code, because is licensed, but I can describe the principle here.
I replaced direct method calls with asynchronous event processing: there is a queue awaiting transactions. Transactions are represented by strings, which must be the same as transaction methods in fsm. They are removed from the queue one by one in an independent thread. Transaction string is transformed to a fsm method call.
This concept proved to work very well in many critical applications. It is rather simple to implement and easy to extend with new features.
Final form of this asynchronous layer had these additional features:

1. Perfect logging: all transactions and their arguments, time of arrival, time of processing ...etc.
2. Possibility to replace the independent thread with an external thread - sometimes it is better to process things in thread provided from outside (Windows GUI is very sensitive to external thread calls...)
3. Preprocessing of transactions - sometimes the system was expected to change state only if a sequence of transaction occured. It is rather clumsy to achieve it directly with SMC. I implemented so called "transaction transformations" - it was possible to declare how a set of transactions is transformed into a single transaction.